# yt:statistics can't be found in youtube feeds

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, youtube, youtube-api

I've been trying to retrieve some videos from youtube using this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds), and things go smoothly until when I add an Upload date filter, the `XML` file does not contain the `yt:statistics` in the `entry` tag. Other then this when I add other filters like Order by, there seem to be no problems.

The Uri I used in the WebClient is this one :

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=example&time=today&max-results=20&v=2
```

So can any one point where is the error I'm making for me?

Thank you.

EDIT:

It seems after placing some breakpoints that the `XML` does contain it but the problem is with the code I used:

```
        XElement downloadedXml = XElement.Parse(xml);

        //extract entries from the xml
        var entries = downloadedXml.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName == "entry");


        foreach (var entry in entries)
        { 
            string views = "";


            //extract the number of views
            views = entry.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName == "statistics").First().Attribute("viewCount").Value;


        }
```

It seems that the `entry` does not contain `yt:statistics`.

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. It seems working for me :)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=example&time=today&max-results=20&v=2");

XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace yt = "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007";
var result = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                    .Where(e => e.Element(yt + "statistics")!=null)
                    .Select(e => e.Element(yt + "statistics")
                                .Attributes()
                                .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value))

                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You are right it seems that the xml does contain it, I'll edit my post

Comment: @User-_- What do you want more? I posted an answer to get all attributes of `yt:statistics`

Comment: @User-_- because all entries do not contain `yt:statistics`. Only some of them. So your codes throws exception in `entry.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName == "statistics").First()` See the where condition in my code.